# What is the significance of &0xff while separiting the RGB channels out from an RGB image?

Tags: java, image-processing

I have the following code snippet

```
for(int row=0; row<r; row++)
{
    for(int col=0; col<c; col++)
    {
        alphaPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[ii]>>24)&0xff);
        redPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[ii]>>16)&0xff);
        greenPixels[row][col] = ((RGBarray[ii]>>8)&0xff);
        bluePixels[row][col] = (RGBarray[ii]&0xff);
        ii++;
    }
}
```

Why do we have to use the bitwise AND operation `& 0xff` after the shifting operation?

Comment: Can we assume that RGBarray is a byte[] array? If you post snippets, at least take the time to make sure that everything inside that snippet is properly specified to the people reading.

Comment: @Gimby: Make an educated guess. This code makes no sense, if it's not a `int` or a `long` array and since `int` is used often for colors, you can assume it's a `int[]` array.

Comment: @Fabian: Gimby probably meant the `alpha/red/green/bluePixels` arrays.

Comment: If the destination arrays are bytes, the masking with 0xff is of no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we have to use the bitwise AND operation ' & 0xff' after the
>   shifting operation?

`Oxff` is hexadecimal number which is equal to decimal 255.

In your case, `& 0xff` ensure all pixel values range be within 0 to 255 (i.e. positive 8 bit). For example, if any value is greater than 255 than it will truncated it within 0-255

```
    int value=257;
    int result = value & 0xff; // result will be 1
```

So, it works like remainder operator `%` of positive value. But bitwise operator `&` is more faster than remainder operator `%`.

```
    int result = value % 256; //You will get same result for positive value
```

Comment: `int result = value % 256; // You will get same result` Not for negative `value`s. Since the shift is not the *unsigned* shift operator, negative values can occur for each color channel.

Comment: @fabian, you're right. For negative value it will not give same result.

Answer (score 1):

`0xff` has integer value of 255.

`>> n` right shifts the number `n` bits, `&` operator performs a *bitwise* AND operation.

So `& 0xff` masks the variable. It leaves only the value in the last *8* bits, and ignores all the rest of the bits.

This is a common trick when you try to transform color values from a special format to standard RGB values (since it has 8-bits).